# Quick Nimble ios test not running

Tags: swift, testing, nimble

I'm trying to use Quick & Nimble to test a project but the test is never executed.

I've created a project from scratch using File->New->Project in Xcode. The project is called "MyApp". Then I created a UnitTest target testing "MyApp".

I've added the following Podfile:

```
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'MyApp' do
  # Pods for Test
  target "MyAppTests" do
  
      pod 'Quick'
      pod 'Nimble'
    end
end
```

I ran "pod install" and everything went well.

Then, I've created a test file:

```
import Quick
import Nimble
@testable import MyApp

class TestSpec: QuickSpec {

    override func spec() {
        describe("Describe test") {
            context("Context test") {
                it("Assertion") {
                    expect("toto") == "tata"
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Then I ran the test. I expected my test to fail but actually: nothing.
It's never executed.
Do you guys have any idea why?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Same as me, not sure if this is M1 or Xcode 13.3, or too low version of Quick/Nimble?

Comment: same here, xcode13.3.1

Answer (score 4):

Quick/Nimble test has a [related bug](https://github.com/Quick/Quick/pull/1129) for Xcode 13.3. I tested both 13.3 and 13.2.1 and only 13.2.1 can run Nimble tests. Might have to wait for the fix to be merged.

Answer (score 2):

The bug mentioned here is already fixed, but what I found out is that default version of Quick being installed is 4.0.0. That is unless you tell it a minimum version desired, like this:

```
pod 'Quick', '~> 5.0.1'
```

This version has the xcode13.3.1 + Nimble bug fixed.